# PHP not displaying/logging ANY errors with NGINX

Tags: php, nginx

Setup:

- CentOS
- php 5.3.6 (php-fpm)
- NGINX 1.0.4

I just CAN'T make php spit any errors, be it on screen or to the log.
I've tried changing settings in php.ini (error_log, error_reporting) but nothing helped.
nginx logs show nothing either, except warnings on site with only a phpinfo() function (warnings about timezone setting, nothing serious).

There are some sites working properly, but when i try to access phpbb forum, server just spits out a blank page with a 500 error code.

What's interesting:
after adding following code to index.php

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

response code changes to 200, but the page is still blank, and I cannot find any error logs whatsoever.

Any ideas?

Edit:
this probalby has something to do with

> include

since I've commented some code and it finally spit out error about uninitialized object.

it seems to be crashing here:

```
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : './';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_display.' . $phpEx);

// Start session management
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup('viewforum');
```

on the include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turned out phpBB as hiding errors from output.
Yet, it would be nice to have an overall error logger despite all settings in php files.